# Extract the data from txt file with various format speification in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to extract Andy's result from the below txt file. My expectation is extracting 1.033, -0.017, 1.016 and put these into the cell array. Is there any possible way to extract these? I have around 100 files with same format as below.

```
Total 6 outlier 0 
| Thomas |      -0.255 |      -0.006 |      -0.261 |
| Todd   |       1.012 |       0.112 |       1.124 |
| Harry  |      -0.033 |       0.005 |      -0.028 |
| Andy   |       1.033 |      -0.017 |       1.016 |
| Zheng  |       0.152 |       0.226 |       0.378 |
| Betsi  |     -19.409 |       1.010 |     -18.399 |
| Andrew |      -0.066 |       0.048 |      -0.018 |
| Tom    |     -95.582 |       0.590 |     -94.991 |
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For the future, you will make yourself a huge favour by considering this before you write the string out. It is much easier to adapt string concatenation rather than string splitting/searching.

Comment: formatting (I hope I didn't "destroy" the "input file format" too much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there is no new line in you text file.

Let's try something:

```
%Open you file and load the data
fid = fopen('the_path_of_your_file');
line = fgetl(fid);
%We split the data using the '||' delimiter. Each personne's results 
%is stored in a cell.
txtSplitCell = strsplit(line,'||');
%Here we check in each cell if 'Andy' appears 
indAndy = cellfun(@(c)strfind(c,'Andy')),...
txtSplitCell,'UniformOutput',false);
%We split the content of Andy's results cell with the second sperator '|'
%to get the values 
resAndyRaw = strsplit(txtSplitCell{find(indAndy,1)},'|');
% We only select the subsection of the cell array that actually contains
%Andy's results (in other words we remove 'Andy' in the results cell
%and we convert that into matrix;
resAndyTab = cell2mat(resAndyRaw(strcmp(resAndyRaw,'Andy'):end));
%Note:  strcmp(resAndyRaw,'Andy') enable locating the postion of
%'Andy' in the resulting cell array of the strsplit function. 
% Consequently thus this code should work for thomas as well.
fclose(fid)
print(resAndyTab)
```

I can't run that code yet (no matlab on my computer). So test it please and correct it if needed.

Bye.